# how to change the android:inputType="phone" to android:inputType="textEmailAddress" from java?

Tags: android

Im a beginner in android and need your advice:

**1.** The app is about to send a message (sms or email) using two radio buttons (SMS or Email).

**2.** When initiating, the SMS radio button will be checked and the EditText for the contact/receiver is on `android:inputType="phone"`

**3.** If i click on the EMAIL radio button i would like the EditText to be changed to `android:inputType="textEmailAddress"`

how can i do this from the MainActivity.java?

Comment: Hi All, allow me to clarify: when sending SMS it will show the phone keyboard (to type the number), so changing the rad button to "textEmailAddress" will provide the email/letter keyboard. Did i make myself clear?. Thx in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the others have said the function to change the input type would be the setInputType function, how you could use it would be a couple of ways.

1. Create a button listener from the code.

   OR use the onClick option in your element. <-- How I would do it personally and shown below

I.E.

```
`<RadioButton android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:onClick="setInputTypeToSMS"
         android:text="SMS">`
`<RadioButton android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:onClick="setInputTypeToEmail"
         android:text="EMAIL">`
```

then in your main activity

```
public class SomeActivity extends Activity{
    private EditText editText;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);

    }
    public void setInputTypeToEmail(View view)
    {
       editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS);
    }
    public void setInputTypeToSMS(View view)
    {
       editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE);
    }
}
```

Comment: see your `setInputTypetoEmail` and `SMS` method, should use `view` instead of `editText`.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you're asking, I am modifying the existing variable editText to be a different type in each routine. Which is (by use of the findViewById) a "pointer" to the xml element that requires different input types.

Comment: then why sending a `View view` to the method? any usage for that? i doubt that?

Comment: I may be wrong but I was under the impression that was how the onClick required the functions, again I could be wrong, this is how I've done it in my apps in the past, however if I don't need the "View view" that would be something I could use. Let me do some checking.

Comment: It appears based on the link here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html its an abstract void. I think that View view (or really View <any variable name>) is necessary for it to work.

Comment: that is because `onClick` method is called when a View is clicked, taking the `View view` parameter because we need to know which `view` is being clicked. And for your `setInputTypetoEmail` and `SMS` method, you are directly change the editText(which is a predefined variable), so no need to take `view` on calling the method.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16399/discussion-between-onaclov2000-and-aprian)

Comment: Thx Onaclov, this code will be very helpful to understand and use.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using this method :

```
et.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS);
```

Comment: Thank you  Aprian, that's what i needed it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it might help you

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `setInputType` method for your `EditText`.

try

```
edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS);
```

for more information [`click here`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html)

Comment: Thank you Ram that's what i needed it.